# Converting a block from Objective-C to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks

I have written the following method that returns a block that I've written in Objective-C. No matter how many times I mess with the syntax I can't get a swift version of this method that the compiler likes.

```
- (TWCInviteAcceptanceBlock)acceptHandler
{
    return ^(TWCConversation * _Nullable conversation, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (conversation) {
             NSLog("Yay")
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Boo")
        }
    };
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Update your question with your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
func acceptHandler() -> TWCInviteAcceptanceBlock {
    return { (conversation: TWCConversation?, error: NSError?) in
        if let conversation = conversation {
             print("Yay")
        } else {
             print("Boo")
        }
    }
}
```